# How to average forward looking data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with values: eg.

```
                         jpy3m      jpy1w
timestamp    

2019-01-09 00:00:00      -45         -25
2019-01-08 00:00:00      -48         -31
2019-01-07 00:00:00      -51         -27
2019-01-04 00:00:00      -46         -25
...
2016-01-06 00:00:00      -61         -26
2016-01-05 00:00:00      -62         -22
2016-01-04 00:00:00      -57         -21
```

The index is from today to the start of 2016. Business days only.

What I wish to process, but am unable to, is, for each day where it is possible to do so, take the value in jpy3m and take away the average of (the value of jpy1w on the same day, but also, the value of jpy1w over the next 11 weeks)

e.g. consider 2016-01-04

take value of jpy3m = -57
take average of jpy 1w on (2016-01-04,2016-01-11(1w later),2016-01-19(2w later (18th is not a good business day),2016-01-25(3w later)....etc, until 2016-03-25(11w later))
lets say this averages -25

then take -25 - (-57) = +32, so +32 is the value for 4th jan

This will go in a new column, df['result']

And repeat for the 5th jan 16, and so forth.

I understand the most recent 3 months wont have a result and will be np.nan

is this possible?

thank you

Comment: Can you provide your dataset?

Comment: How would you know which is a "good" business day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that if the day is not a good business day then that record is not in your dataset. If it is in your dataset then you can remove those records.

Sort records in descending order of time.

we are averaging current value with next 7th, 14th, ...., 77th values.

```
avgs = df['jpy1w'].copy()

for i in range(11):
    avgs = df['jpy1w'].shift(7*(i+1)) + avgs

avgs = avgs/12
df['result'] = df['jpy3m'] + avgs
```

Comment: Thanks @Nishant. I actually needed only the dates in 1w, and in 2w, etc, averaged. Thus, im looking to average todays value plus 11 future values. does that make sense?